# Express, Mongoose, Jest sometimes failed sometimes pass

Tags: jestjs

I want to make integration testing with MonggoDB.
I use jest and mongoose.

My code sometimes pass, sometimes not.
I'v search for two days, and modify the code. But it doesn't solve the problem.

I currently only have two test file:
here is my repo: https://github.com/tsulatsitamim/sia-server/tree/d6a211f2dc773f4469c988dd9746b206a398d67f/test/integration

[PASS TEST](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNO5m.png)

[FAILED TEST](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x5FMy.png)

[OTHER FAILED TEST](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HUfY4.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happen because conflict between test file when populating the database. Solved by create unique name of document, of each test file. and delete document by its name.